# Raspberry pi camera start_preview() screen not shown?

Tags: camera

Hello I've tried to see the preview of picamera via both VNC viewer and SSH from my mac, after I use something like `camera.start_preview()` I got

```
<picamera.renderers.PiPreviewRenderer object at 0x75cb0390>
```

but there is no screen shown the preview...

I use Raspberry Pi 2 Model B V1.1, OS X, I installed both python2 and 3.

Comment: The camera preview is not sent over VNC, it can only be viewed on a  monitor connected to the Pi. Since the camera preview is handled on a low level in the GPU. [This](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29537/sending-raspberry-pi-camera-preview-to-a-laptop-running-vnc-viewer) might help you though.

Comment: @DarthVader Thank you so much. How should I use if I want to see the camera preview directly in VNC?

Comment: If you're using the RealVNC server on the Pi, go to VNC options > troubleshooting and enable "experimental direct capture mode", then you'll be able to view the camera preview image over the vnc connection.

Answer (score 0):

@N1ng Personally its good if you use HDMI monitors or Displays for camera preview , Because the Preview is not supported in Pitft screens ,However for SSH  [See this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29537/sending-raspberry-pi-camera-preview-to-a-laptop-running-vnc-viewer)