# How to access pi camera with OpenCV to Laptop?

Tags: pi-3, opencv, laptop

I do not have HDMI supported monitor for `Raspberry pi 3`. I want to use `OpenCV` with my pi camera for image processing and access those images and videos with OpenCV image output to my **LAPTOP**, which is connected to raspberry pi with putty and wifi.

Please help me to understand how can I do this ?

UPDATE :

I have used VNC Server but when I run program, NO ERROR, but I can't see any output window there. Screenshot attached below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do would be to [Run a VNCserver](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/). This way you can login to your pi, much like you do through putty, but with access to the GUI desktop.

**Update:** 
Oops, it looks like this has been [tried before](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29537/sending-raspberry-pi-camera-preview-to-a-laptop-running-vnc-viewer). Apparently the `raspistill` and `raspivid` command line tools [won't show up over VNC either](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=64374&p=475612).

Since you said you are planning on using openCV, I would try using OpenCV's GUI to show the image:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep

# Also import these two modules
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
import cv2

# Set up PiCamera and let it warm up
camera = PiCamera()
raw = PiRGBArray(camera)
time.sleep(0.1)


# Capture to a PiRGBArray
camera.capture(raw, format="bgr")
image = raw.array

# Use OpenCV's gui to show the image
cv2.imshow("Preview", image)
cv2.waitKey(0) # Wait for key press to close preview
```

I think this should be visible over VNC.

Comment: I have used VNCserver but still it is not showing OUTPUT window. program is running fine but no display.

Comment: @AbhishekTandon I've updated my comment. I think using the OpenCV GUI should work, but I have not been able to test it (I'm at work).

Comment: what is the solution to this problem? opencv GUI is not working either