# Streaming from the pi camera to a website

Tags: camera, streaming-video, streaming

Hi so I would like to stream video from my raspi to a streaming service like twitch. I have setup my pi using [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/23205) answer, but that only lets me stream inside my local network.

I do have another computer that can take the info from the pi to the service if needed. It's currently running windows 7 but I can install linux if needed.

Comment: Welcome -- but if this is a question about how to use twitch, then the pi is irrelevant and you should ask somewhere with a density of twitch, not pi, users.   Note this is a Q&A format, not a discussion forum and so vague, open ended questions are not appropriate.  Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) if you have not yet.

Comment: I'm sorry if I am using these forums incorrectly, but i'm just not sure how to get video from the pi camera to a program like OBS where it has dozens of tutorials on how to get from that to twitch. Also I don't have a certain streaming provider (like twitch). I am new to all the streaming stuff and don't know if one site is easier than the others.