# Picamera stream frame

Tags: video, streaming-video

I'm using Picamera with my Raspberry Pi model 2B.

I want to stream the video on VLC in which I got succeed, but now I'm wondering if there is a way to stream this captured frame from anywhere - browser etc.

I followed this tutorial which gave me the frame for some sec in the last.
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: So you want to stream the video to a web browser?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a [RTP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/23205) Stream?

Have a look at flowplayer.  I used it a long time ago to help me present streamed video content in a browser.  Looks like their pricing model has changed but there is still a free option.

A quick google for HTML5 RTP Stream Video returns a few possible options.  Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203207/what-support-for-live-streaming-does-the-html5-video-element-have) and let us know how you get on as would be interested to hear.

Answer (score -1):

Try [UV4L](http://linux-projects.org) It can stream to any browser or to Jitsi Meet Web Conferences.