# Unable to stream video on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: camera, video, streaming-video

Following some of the answers in [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23182/how-to-stream-video-from-raspberry-pi-camera-and-watch-it-live), I tried setting up an RTSP stream by running:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -hf -w 640 -h 360 -fps 25 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554}' :demux=h264
```

but this seems to fail with the output:

```
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28)
[0x1e320d0] main libvlc debug: VLC media player - 2.1.6 Rincewind
[0x1e320d0] main libvlc debug: Copyright �� 1996-2015 the VideoLAN team 
[0x1e320d0] main libvlc debug: revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28
[0x1e320d0] main libvlc debug: configured with ./configure  '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--localstatedir=/var' '--libdir=${prefix}/lib/arm-lin
ux-gnueabihf' '--libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--build=arm-linux-gnueabihf' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro' '--conf
ig-cache' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-silent-rules' '--disable-update-check' '--enable-fast-install' '--prefix=/usr' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/vlc-nox' '--libdir=/usr/lib' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--with-b
inary-version=0ubuntu14.04.1' '--enable-a52' '--enable-aa' '--enable-bluray' '--enable-bonjour' '--enable-caca' '--enable-chromaprint' '--enable-dbus' '--enable-dca' '--enable-dirac' '--enable-directfb' '--enabl
e-dvbpsi' '--enable-dvdnav' '--enable-faad' '--enable-flac' '--enable-fluidsynth' '--enable-freetype' '--enable-fribidi' '--enable-gnutls' '--enable-jack' '--enable-kate' '--enable-libass' '--enable-libfreerdp' 
'--enable-libmpeg2' '--enable-libxml2' '--enable-lirc' '--enable-live555' '--enable-mad' '--enable-mkv' '--enable-mod' '--enable-mpc' '--enable-mtp' '--enable-mux_ogg' '--enable-ncurses' '--enable-notify' '--ena
ble-ogg' '--enable-opus' '--enable-oss' '--enable-pulse' '--enable-qt' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-samplerate' '--enable-schroedinger' '--enable-sdl' '--enable-sftp' '--enable-shout' '--enable-skins2' '--enabl
e-smbclient' '--enable-speex' '--enable-svg' '--enable-taglib' '--enable-theora' '--enable-twolame' '--enable-upnp' '--enable-vcd' '--enable-vcdx' '--enable-vorbis' '--enable-x264' '--enable-zvbi' '--with-kde-so
lid=/usr/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/' '--disable-decklink' '--disable-dxva2' '--disable-fdkaac' '--disable-gnomevfs' '--disable-goom' '--disable-libvnc' '--disable-opencv' '--disable-projectm' '--disable-quic
ksync' '--disable-sndio' '--disable-telx' '--disable-vsxu' '--disable-wasapi' '--enable-alsa' '--enable-atmo' '--enable-dc1394' '--enable-dv1394' '--enable-linsys' '--enable-omxil' '--enable-udev' '--enable-libv
a' '--enable-v4l2' '--disable-crystalhd' '--disable-mmx' '--disable-sse' '--disable-neon' '--disable-altivec' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'CXXFLAG
S=-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'build_alias=arm-linux-gnueabihf'
[0x1e320d0] main libvlc debug: searching plug-in modules
[0x1e320d0] main libvlc debug: loading plugins cache file /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates

[0x1e320d0] main libvlc debug: recursively browsing `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins'
[0x1e320d0] main libvlc debug: saving plugins cache /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
[0x1e320d0] main libvlc debug: plug-ins loaded: 392 modules
[0x1e320d0] main libvlc debug: opening config file (/home/ubuntu/.config/vlc/vlcrc)
[0x1e320d0] main libvlc debug: translation test: code is "C"
[0x1e320d0] main libvlc debug: CPU has capabilities ARM_NEON FPU
[0x1eca128] main input debug: Creating an input for 'Media Library'
[0x1eca128] main input debug: Input is a meta file: disabling unneeded options
[0x1eca128] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path '/tmp'
[0x1eca128] main input debug: `file/xspf-open:///home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' gives access `file' demux `xspf-open' path `/home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0x1eca128] main input debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='xspf-open' location='/home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0x1e45d18] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module matching "file": 18 candidates
[0x1e45d18] main demux debug: no access_demux modules matched
[0x1eca128] main input debug: creating access 'file' location='/home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf', path='/home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0x1eca958] main access debug: looking for access module matching "file": 25 candidates
[0x1eca958] filesystem access debug: opening file `/home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0x1eca958] main access debug: using access module "filesystem"
[0x1e45d18] main stream debug: Using stream method for AStream*
[0x1e45d18] main stream debug: starting pre-buffering
[0x1e45d18] main stream debug: received first data after 0 ms
[0x1e45d18] main stream debug: pre-buffering done 296 bytes in 0s - 1927 KiB/s
[0x1ecaf80] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 9 candidates
[0x1ecaf80] main stream debug: no stream_filter modules matched
[0x1ecaf80] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 9 candidates
[0x1ecaf80] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "record"
[0x1eca128] main input debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='xspf-open' location='/home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0x1ecc9a8] main demux debug: looking for demux module matching "xspf-open": 63 candidates
[0x1ecc9a8] playlist demux debug: using XSPF playlist reader
[0x1ecc9a8] main demux debug: using demux module "playlist"
[0x1ece128] main demux meta debug: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
[0x1ece128] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x1ece128] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x1ece128] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/reader/filename.luac
[0x1ece128] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x1ece128] main demux meta debug: no meta reader modules matched
[0x1eca128] main input debug: `file/xspf-open:///home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' successfully opened
[0x1ebf340] main xml reader debug: looking for xml reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
[0x1ebf340] main xml reader debug: using xml reader module "xml"
[0x1ecc9a8] playlist demux debug: parsed 0 tracks successfully
[0x1eca128] main input debug: EOF reached
[0x1ecc9a8] main demux debug: removing module "playlist"
[0x1ecaf80] main stream debug: removing module "record"
[0x1eca958] main access debug: removing module "filesystem"
[0x1e44718] main playlist debug: creating audio output
[0x1ebe998] main audio output debug: looking for audio output module matching "any": 5 candidates
[0x1ebe998] alsa audio output debug: Available ALSA PCM devices:
[0x1ebe998] alsa audio output debug: Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture) (null)
[0x1ebe998] alsa audio output debug: bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA Default Audio Device (default:CARD=ALSA)
[0x1ebe998] alsa audio output debug: bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA Default Audio Device (sysdefault:CARD=ALSA)
[0x1ebe998] alsa audio output debug: bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA Direct sample mixing device (dmix:CARD=ALSA,DEV=0)
[0x1ebe998] alsa audio output debug: bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI Direct sample mixing device (dmix:CARD=ALSA,DEV=1)
[0x1ebe998] alsa audio output debug: bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA Direct sample snooping device (dsnoop:CARD=ALSA,DEV=0)
[0x1ebe998] alsa audio output debug: bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI Direct sample snooping device (dsnoop:CARD=ALSA,DEV=1)
[0x1ebe998] alsa audio output debug: bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA Direct hardware device without any conversions (hw:CARD=ALSA,DEV=0)
[0x1ebe998] alsa audio output debug: bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI Direct hardware device without any conversions (hw:CARD=ALSA,DEV=1)
[0x1ebe998] alsa audio output debug: bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA Hardware device with all software conversions (plughw:CARD=ALSA,DEV=0)
[0x1ebe998] alsa audio output debug: bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI Hardware device with all software conversions (plughw:CARD=ALSA,DEV=1)
[0x1ebe998] main audio output debug: using audio output module "alsa"   
[0x1e44718] main playlist debug: keeping audio output
[0x1e44718] main playlist debug: adding item `stdin' ( stream:///dev/stdin )
[0x765004d8] main input debug: Creating an input for 'stdin'
[0x1eca958] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "hotkeys,none": 15 candidates
[0x1e44718] main playlist debug: no fetch required for (null) (art currently (null))
[0x1eca958] main interface debug: using interface module "hotkeys"
[0x1e45498] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "globalhotkeys,none": 15 candidates
[0x1e45498] main interface debug: no interface modules matched
[0x1e45498] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x1e320d0] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0x1e45498] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "dbus,none": 15 candidates
[0x1e45498] dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[0x1e45498] main interface debug: no interface modules matched
[0x1e45498] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x1e320d0] main libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
[0x1e45498] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "dummy": 15 candidates
[0x1e45498] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[0x1e45498] main interface debug: using interface module "dummy"
[0x1e44718] main playlist debug: processing request item: null, node: Playlist, skip: 0
[0x1e44718] main playlist debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
[0x1e44718] main playlist debug: rebuild done - 1 items, index -1
[0x1e44718] main playlist debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
[0x1e44718] main playlist debug: resyncing on stdin
[0x1e44718] main playlist debug: stdin is at 0
[0x1e44718] main playlist debug: creating new input thread
[0x76502ad8] main input debug: Creating an input for 'stdin'
[0x763006d8] main stream output debug: using sout chain=`rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554}'
[0x763006d8] main stream output debug: stream=`rtp'
[0x763008c8] main stream out debug: looking for sout stream module matching "rtp": 21 candidates
[0x763008c8] main stream out debug: set config option: sout-rtp-sdp to rtsp://:8554
[0x763008c8] stream_out_rtp stream out debug: RTSP stream at /
[0x763008c8] main stream out debug: net: listening to * port 8554
[0x763008c8] main stream out debug: using sout stream module "stream_out_rtp"
[0x76502ad8] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path '/tmp'
[0x76502ad8] main input debug: `stream:///dev/stdin' gives access `stream' demux `' path `/dev/stdin'
[0x76502ad8] main input debug: enforced demux ` h264'
[0x76502ad8] main input debug: creating demux: access='stream' demux='h264' location='/dev/stdin' file='/dev/stdin'
[0x76302658] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module matching "stream": 18 candidates
[0x76302658] main demux debug: no access_demux modules matched
[0x76502ad8] main input debug: creating access 'stream' location='/dev/stdin', path='/dev/stdin'
[0x76302980] main access debug: looking for access module matching "stream": 25 candidates
[0x76302980] filesystem access debug: opening file `/dev/stdin'
[0x76302980] main access debug: using access module "filesystem"
[0x76302a68] main stream debug: Using stream method for AStream*
[0x76302a68] main stream debug: starting pre-buffering
[0x76302a68] main stream error: cannot pre fill buffer
[0x76302980] main access debug: removing module "filesystem"
[0x76502ad8] main input warning: cannot create a stream_t from access
[0x1e44718] main playlist debug: dead input
[0x763006d8] main stream output debug: destroying useless sout
[0x763008c8] main stream out debug: destroying chain... (name=rtp)
[0x763008c8] main stream out debug: removing module "stream_out_rtp"
[0x763024a0] main http host debug: HTTP host removed
[0x763008c8] main stream out debug: destroying chain done
[0x1e44718] main playlist debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
[0x1e44718] main playlist debug: nothing to play
```

This does create stream, but when I access it via VLC on a separate host, VLC just gives me an endless list of errors about not being able to read any data.

I'm assuming this is related to the error in the ouput:

```
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

However, I'm able to use the `picamera` Python module to capture still images from the camera. Why is VLC unable to access the camera?

Comment: [This](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=44491) discussion has what looks to be relevant information. Can you check ps aux for any running instances that might be interfering with things?

Comment: seems like a permissions problem... did you try to run it as root? (sudo)