# Using Two Pis To Send USB Data Over LAN Network

Tags: networking, usb

I'm wondering if it's possible to have one pi taking in USB data from a device then sending it to another pi over an LAN network which then shows up like it's the device on the other end. Trying to hookup a camera to remote control it but the usb over ethernet adapter I'm using seems to be pretty flakey. Figured I'd see if this is a possible solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

(Warning: I've never tried this myself.) The Linux kernel has usbip-utils, which offer USB via IP, and there's a [usbip-utils README](https://www.kernel.org/doc/readme/tools-usb-usbip-README) included. This readme includes usage sections for the server side, as well as the client side. These are rather low-level tools in that you need to look up the device bus IDs to be made available via IP. The readme walks you through these steps.

Answer (score 0):

If a dedicated USB-over-Ethernet adapter seems flaky to you, I bet you will be disappointed by the speed of USB-over-Ethernet implemented using the RPi which is not optimized for this use-case.

One thing that might work is using the RPi to [produce a video stream](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23182/how-to-stream-video-from-raspberry-pi-camera-and-watch-it-live) and transmit that (compressed) data over the network. You will need to figure out a way to remote-control your camera, which will be done outside of the video stream. Possible solutions include SSH, Remote desktop, or something like [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy).

Comment: Thanks. You might be right but I think the issue is actually that the camera doesn't put out a strong signal so it can't go the distance vs a bandwidth issue. The actual data should be pretty small. We're running the actual video over SDI to a switcher.