# How to stop a cvnc stream

Tags: streaming

I have a (headless) raspberry pi zero w with cameramodule. From this topic:

[How to stream video from Raspberry Pi camera and watch it live](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23182/how-to-stream-video-from-raspberry-pi-camera-and-watch-it-live)

I found how to stream this to VLC on my pc or phone. And it works (although a bit laggy) fine. However, the only way I can find to stop the stream is to CTRL+C out which lets me control the pi via putty again, but it leaves the camara enabled and it makes it impossible to restart another stream without rebooting the pi.

I have tried every combination of cvnc:exit, stop, cancel, quit etc. With and without the cvnc before it. But I cant get it to stop streaming. And there are about a milion topics on every site starting the stream. But I couldn't find even one that tells me how to stop it on command (not by timer).

How can I stop the stream?