# How to stream video from raspberry pi?

Tags: video, streaming-video, php

I own a raspberry pi model B+.
A webpage is hosted on raspberry pi and i want to display a real time video stream from a webcam.The stream should be embedded on the web page (shown below)

[image: video object on HTML page]

The webcam is attached to raspberry pi via USB.
Is it possible to acquire the video stream from raspberry pi using php coding and display it as a video object on HTML web page ? If yes how ?
Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the [most upvoted answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/7615/5538) on the dupe question, you'll see how to chunkify the stream with `ffmpeg` and then use the HTML 5 `video` tag, which I think is what you want to do here.

Answer (score 2):

I think this covers what you are asking for:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-remote-webcam/