# Raspberry pi Webcam stream with ffmpeg

Tags: webcam, ffmpeg

Hello i am using ffserver with ffmpeg to stream a video with audio from web cam. The ffserver.conf file is :

```
Port 80
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxClients 10
MaxBandwidth 50000
NoDaemon

<Feed webcam.ffm>
  file /tmp/webcam.ffm
  FileMaxSize 10M
</Feed>

<Stream webcam.avi>
Feed webcam.ffm
Format avi
VideoSize 176x128
VideoFrameRate 15
VideoBufferSize 40
VideoBitRate 64
AudioBitRate 32
AudioChannels 1
AudioSampleRate 11025
VideoQMin 1
VideoQMax 20
</Stream>

<Stream stat.html>
Format status
</Stream>
```

And the command i am executing is :

```
ffserver -f /root/ff.conf & ffmpeg -vcodec mjpeg -v verbose -r 15 -s 176x128 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:1 http://localhost:81/webcam.ffm
```

The problem is that i cant see the stream through the web. Is there any other way to fix that or stream a video with audio through webcam? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I stream H.264 video from the Raspberry Pi camera module via a web server?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7446/how-can-i-stream-h-264-video-from-the-raspberry-pi-camera-module-via-a-web-serve)

Comment: If connection is OK, the the problem is that the video stream is missing datestamp of frames. This is a known problem on the hardware h264 encoder on the pi and requires a manual intervention after packet dump and before broadcast. The client does not know how to synchronise frames after recieving it

Answer (score 0):

My `/etc/ffserver.conf` is

```
Port 8090
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 10000
NoDaemon
File /tmp/feed1.ffm
FileMaxSize 5M
Feed feed1.ffm
Format mpjpeg
VideoFrameRate 2
VideoIntraOnly
NoAudio
Strict -1*
```

More detail, you can see tutorial here: http://engineer2you.blogspot.com/2016/10/rasbperry-pi-ffmpeg-install-and-stream.html

Comment: Hello and welcome. We're [trying a new policy with regard to informationless link-only answers here](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538). If this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community. While your post is **not** link-only, as it shows the config, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to provide a little more context here. Please include the essential parts that make the reader understand how and why it works.