# How to stream low-latency video from the RPi to a web browser in realtime

Tags: video, streaming-video, html5

I took me a while of hunting, but I managed to get low-latency real-time video streaming working on my RPi2.

I'm running this on my RPi2:

```
raspivid -t 999999 -h 720 -w 1280 -fps 25 -b 2000000 -vf -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=0.0.0.0 port=8554
```

and I can consume this stream on an Ubuntu 14 laptop with gstreamer like:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v tcpclientsrc host=myrpi.local port=8554 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

However, I want to view this stream in a web browser (Firefox or Chrome) using the [HTML5 video tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp). Apparently, both [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) and [Chrome's](http://www.chromium.org/audio-video) implementation of this tag support the video format Ogg, WebM, and MP4 H.264.

If I'm understanding the raspivid/gstreamer commands correctly, it's streaming and consuming H.264 video? However, when I try to consume this via the tag with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 
    <video controls autoplay>
      <source src="http://rae.local:8554">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</body> 
</html>
```

Firefox and Chrome say it's in an invalid format.

Is there any way to get a low-latency video stream from the RPi that works with the `<video>` tag? I've seen some examples of using WebRTC or FFMpeg, but these all have 20-30s of latency and don't work with raspivid.

Edit: I followed [these instructions](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14) to install UV4L via a custom repo and I managed to get the uv4l server running with:

```
uv4l -nopreview --auto-video_nr --driver raspicam --encoding mjpeg --width 640 --height 480 --framerate 20 --hflip=yes --vflip=yes --bitrate=2000000 --server-option '--port=9090' --server-option '--max-queued-connections=30' --server-option '--max-streams=25' --server-option '--max-threads=29'
```

I was then able to access the web UI at `http://mypi.local:9090/`. It also serves a page for streaming mjpeg that works even outside the server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>UV4L Stream</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function errorFunction() {
                alert('Stream stopped');
            }
        </script>
        <img src="http://mypi.local:9090/stream/video.mjpeg" alt="image"  >
    </body>
</html>
```

However, this clearly doesn't use the HTML5 `<video>` tag. I then tried the WebRTC example page, and this does appear to run in the browser, but it's heavily Javascript based, so I can't tell exactly how it's implemented or if I can reuse it in my own application.

Comment: I notice from the w3schools page [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) that all of the examples include a type definition chosen from 3 container options (type="video/[mp4/ogg/webm]". I'm not sure that gstreamer sends this without prompting, so you're likely to need it in your HTML. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810640/gstreamer-tcpserversink-v0-10-vs-1-0-and-html5-video-tag) SO thread has some (apparently) functional gstreamer strings that might be worth investigating.

Comment: You'll have 10-20 seconds lag, but the you get 30fps full HD. Send me a message. HLS/ffmpeg is what you'd use.

Comment: @1'' he said realtime,10-20s is not realtime, hls/ffmpeg is not either. only uv4l is realtime.

Comment: I think using the Video for Linux 2 (`v4l2`) API driver (official one from the Raspberry Pi Foundation) to stream data straight from the camera is better than using `raspivid`. I'm trying a udp stream with cVLC (`sudo apt-get install vlc`), using memory mapped I/O (mmap) options for `v4l2-ctl` and I would convert this to a `mpeg-dash` stream on the Pi to view the video over HTTP in a web browser. This is untested. Also see the related question  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7446/how-can-i-stream-h-264-video-from-the-raspberry-pi-camera-module-via-a-web-serve?rq=1.

Comment: Try [raspiwebcam](https://github.com/soyersoyer/raspiwebcam)! It works without javascript, it doesn't have dependencies other than python and raspivid. It adds fragmented mp4 header to the h264 stream at server side.

Answer (score 7):

You can send raw 264 frames to a browser through websocket and decode in in javascript. Latency < 0.1s :p
I wrote an opensource project in this manner, checkout https://github.com/131/h264-live-player

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest way to stream to a browser is [UV4L](http://linux-projects.org) with WebRTC (much better than mjpeg). It works "out-of-the-box" with the embedded streaming server. No command sauces are required. It optionally supports audio as well. Audio and/or video can be bidirectional. The streaming server can load customized pages too. With chrome (much better than Firefox) latency can be as low as 150ms with Full HD hardware-encoded h264.

Comment: The problem with the UV4l solution is that (a) it is closed source and (b) it will overlay the project url on your videos.

Comment: I like webrtc from uv4l for this, but I can't find a simple javascript shim to serve up the video :/ most of the examples are way too complicated and based on assumptions that it is being used for video conferencing.

Answer (score 0):

Try my [fmp4streamer](https://github.com/soyersoyer/fmp4streamer) project! It works without javascript, it doesn't have dependencies other than python and V4L2. It adds fragmented mp4 header to the h264 stream at server side.

Comment: You should disclose this is your project, as does the top ranked answer here currently.