# CM Stream Dual Cameras simultaneously

Tags: camera, raspicam, streaming-video, streaming, compute-module

I'm a beginner user. My goal is to stream low-latency dual cameras to pc, and then record&save the videos.

Using the Compute Module & IO Board, I have done this: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/cmio-camera.md

I tested with raspistill -cs 0 & raspistill -cs 1 , and I know both cam 0&1 works.

So now, how do I turn on both cameras simultaneously?

Reading this: [How can I stream H.264 video from the Raspberry Pi camera module via a web server?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7446/how-can-i-stream-h-264-video-from-the-raspberry-pi-camera-module-via-a-web-serve)
It seems like Raspberry Pi Cam Web interface & 
U4VL are the two available streaming solutions.

And looking at the UV4L dual camera example, it seems like you will need to use 2 different formats (H264&mjpeg) to start 2 separate streams?
http://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/tutorials/dual-cameras/

I'm not sure if Raspberry Pi Cam Web interface support dual camera stream, but it seems like the UV4L is the ultimate answer?

Comment: Use the stereoscopic option in whatever you're using to access the camera (e.g. `--stereo` with raspivid, the `stereo_mode` option in the PiCamera constructor, and presumably some command line switch with uv4l). This will output a single stream with the output of each camera arranged side-by-side or top-and-bottom (depending on other options).